# Facing This isse Unresolved reference: R setContentView(R.layout.activity_init_user_info)

Tags: android

Facing This isse Unresolved reference: R setContentView(R.layout.activity_init_user_info)

i also did project clean but i still getting this error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

try to type this line with the import statements

`import com.example.android.R;`

Hint: change {com.example.android} with your real package name.

Comment: now its showing this error import com.fintnessathome.fintnessathomeapp.android.R; Unresolved reference: android

Comment: I think your package name does not include the "android" word, if I am right delete it from the import statement.

Comment: when i removed the "android" now it showing same error Unresolved reference: R

Comment: can you please provide me your package name that typed in AndroidManifest file

Comment: <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="fintnessathome.cardioexcercise"
    android:installLocation="internalOnly">

Comment: and error page is Inituserinforactivtity   package com.fintnessathome.fintnessathomeapp  is this at where Unresolved reference: R error is shown.

Comment: try to use this line now "import fintnessathome.cardioexcercise.R"

Comment: now it showing this error setContentView(R.layout.water_activity_main) Unresolved reference: R... (note i just want to change template of old app, i want to change it and make my own app by changing name and pakage name.

Comment: I think you have a problem with changing your package name. make sure that the package name inside the "AndroidManifest" file is the same as the package name you use inside your classes and "build.gradel (app)" file

Comment: i add package="fintnessathome.cardioexcercise in all pages, now its working but there is another error name error: package R does not exist
        MobileAds.initialize(context2, String.valueOf(R.string.admob_app_id));

Comment: make sure all of your activity is declared right without errors inside your "AndroidManifest" file after you change the activity class package name

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced something like this, and the way I solved it was by writing the following code

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_menu_fragment, container, false)
}
```

Don't forget to change the id "activity *menu* fragment" with the id you have